# Convert values into keys for an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of objects like so:

```
[{name: John, year: 2011, age: "65+", value: 2},
{name: John, year: 2012, age: "65+", value: 5},
{name: Bob, year: 2011, age: "18 under", value: 2}]
```

I'd like to  convert this array of objects into the following:

```
[{name: John, age: "65+", 2011: 2, 2012: 5},
{name: Bob, age: "18 under", 2011: 2, 2012: NA}]
```

You'll notice that I've converted the year values into actual keys. How do I go about this efficiently?

Comment: Are the entries for a given name always together in the array (contiguous)?

Comment: I'm confused about your requirements. There's probably going to have to be an "inner" loop somewhere, and inner loops don't necessarily make an algorithm inefficient.

Comment: @Jerfov2, If there is an efficient way of doing it even with inner loops I am ok.

Comment: @Ry yes you can guarantee that the names will be together

Comment: sounds like premature optimization.  unless you are dealing with a truly enormous amount of values, you really don't need to worry about optimizing this.  but right, you can use a map of counters

Comment: So, are you using name + age like a key?  Or are the repeated age values just redundant data?

Comment: @user12024, I think all the keys except for "Year" can constitute the primary key. After all, the person may change age groups throughout time.

Comment: @somethingstrang doesn't that mean that it's not the primary key?  the age should be overwritten with the oldest age group?

Comment: Sorry, yes name+age is the primary key

Answer (score 2):

You could group the data and collect all keys and apply later the missing years.

```js
var data = [{ name: 'John', year: 2011, age: "65+", value: 2 }, { name: 'John', year: 2012, age: "65+", value: 5 }, { name: 'Bob', year: 2011, age: "18 under", value: 2 }],
    years = new Set;
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, { name, year, value, ...o }) => {
            r[name] = r[name] || { name, ...o };
            r[name][year] = value;
            years.add(year);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(
            (y => o => ({ ...y, ...o }))
            (Object.fromEntries([...years].map(y => [y, NaN])))
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You should not add all dates to each object, so the second object of the array should not have a key `"2012"` at all, and so on if there are lot of dates, then lot of useless keys are added to each object

Comment: @SaymoinSam, please see op's request.

Comment: I don't know if he really wants that behaviour or that's what he tried to do!

Comment: This looks promising. Would this work if we added another variable, like "Age Group"?

Comment: @somethingstrang, how does the data look like and how the result?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated the main post to reflect this input output

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by processing the array one element at a time and creating a new object every time you see a new name:

```js
function* groupByName(entries) {
    let group = null;

    for (const {name, year, value} of entries) {
        if (group === null || group.name !== name) {
            if (group !== null) {
                yield group;
            }
            
            group = {name};
        }

        group[year] = value;
    }

    if (group !== null) {
        yield group;
    }
}

const entries = [
    {name: 'John', year: 2011, value: 2},
    {name: 'John', year: 2012, value: 5},
    {name: 'Bob', year: 2011, value: 2},
];

console.log([...groupByName(entries)]);
```